# In shell script psql command is giving an error. But if I run it manually in terminal its running with out any error

Tags: bash, shell, psql

I am trying to run a shell script that run sql file from the given location and result out put create a file in another location. My problem is when I run the script it giving an error saying 
"syntax error: unexpected end of file" from following line.

```
psql -h 192.168.1.550 -U myuser -d DBONE -f /home/dbfunction/scripts/test.sql
```

my error code is like this,

```
if [ "$filename" != "*" ]; then
psql -h 192.168.1.550 -U myuser -d DBONE &> /home/dbfunction/results/report.txt -f /home/dbfunction/scripts/test.sql << EOF
EOF
fi
```

if i run the same command in terminal from the same location its running without any error. My manual running command is,

```
psql -h 192.168.1.550 -U myuser -d DBONE &> /home/dbfunction/results/report.txt -f /home/dbfunction/scripts/test.sql
```

I removed psql command line and EOF line and added some echo. Its working without any error. I think there is an issue between << EOF and EOF

Can anybody help me to resolve this??

Comment: You don't need `EOF`. Just use the same command you would as running manually. i.e. Remove the `<<EOF...EOF` lines

Comment: Got the error..  There was a space between EOF. Thanks all.. Issue fixed.

Comment: Like I said... You don't *need* it. Using a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is only useful if you're going to put something in it...